# Number of permittable numbers given following conditions.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

What are total numbers belonging to $\mathbb Q$ (rational) between $2008$ and $2009$ such that after decimal point their digits occur in decreasing order? 
\begin{align}
1) &\ 9Pi;i\in [1,9], \\
2) &\ 9Pi;i\in[0-9], \\
3) &\ 2^9-1, \\
4) &\ 2^{10}-1.
\end{align}

I find this tricky as I couldnt exactly figure out a logic. I found out only ways where $9$ was fixed at first place. Thanks !

Comment: What have you tried?  Is $9Pi$ supposed to be the permutations of $i$ items chosen from $9$? Do the first two choices specify a number?  Is decreasing supposed to be strict?  Does $2008\frac 79$ count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Since the digits are after the decimal point, we do not care about terminal zeros.  For instance, $2008.320 = 2008.32$.  Thus, any permissible string of decreasing digits after the decimal point can be found by selecting a non-empty subset of the numbers in the string $987654321$.  For instance, the rational number between $2008$ and $2009$ with decimal expansion $2008.7431$ corresponds to the choice $98\color{blue}{7}65\color{blue}{43}2\color{blue}{1}$.  How many such subsets are there?

Comment: $2^9-1$ right?..

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Choose any sub-sequence from "987654321":

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{9}\binom9n=2^9-1$$